# retrieve database into JTextField

Tags: java, ms-access-2010

i'm doing a project where i need to retrieve data from one field of access and display it on JTextField and its serial no.`select fieldname from tablename`
but it'l select all rows.also how to retrieve data(whole row) with random serial number

Comment: Is your question about how to write the correct SQL statements or something else?

Comment: ya.i want to retrieve a row from access according to sl.no.also i want to use random serial no

Comment: That's covered by the most basic SQL references out there. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the query to select the field data,

```
SELECT fieldName FROM tableName WHERE columnName = 'columnValue';
```

Here, `columnName` should be something like the primary key and `columnValue` will be a unique value (like a serial number). Then it will return the field data associated with the row with the specific `columnValue`.

For setting it into the `JTextField`,

```
if(resultSet.first()) {
    jTextField.setText(resultSet.getString(0));
}
```

Here, `resultSet` should return only one value (with the query specified above).

As for your other question, if your serials are irregular, get all the serials from the table:

```
SELECT serials FROM yourTable;
```

And then add them to a `Collection` (like a `Vector`). Then write an algorithm to generate a random index and retrieve the data from the Collection with that index (`vector.elementAt([yourIndex])`).

Then again query the table in the database for the row associated with that serial:

```
SELECT FROM yourTable WHERE serialNo = 'theValueYouGot';
```

...and you'll get the relevant row.